# Iframe-Resizer, Iframe height set to 0px upon calling window.parentIFrame.scrollTo(0,0)

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, iframe-resizer

[image]

I have a button that I have applied

```js
$('.l_men_but').click(function(){
 window.parentIFrame.scrollTo(0,0);
 return false;
});
```

When the button is clicked the view of the page completely changes so I am looking to scroll the user to the top of the page.

This scrollto functions seems to work well, although the return false; seems to be required for this to take affect.

The issue I am seeing is that on certain browsers, including chrome, IE and mobile browsers, when the button is clicked the parent view scrolls to the top but the iframes height element changes to 0px?

Upon resizing the screen the iframe resizes again to the correct size.

Looking at the console log upon pressing the button I see the following:-

```
iFrameSizer][iFrameSizer0] Trigger event: Mouse Down
iframeResizer.contentWindow.js:140 [iFrameSizer][iFrameSizer0] No change in size detected
iframeResizer.contentWindow.js:140 [iFrameSizer][iFrameSizer0] Trigger event: Mouse Up
iframeResizer.contentWindow.js:140 [iFrameSizer][iFrameSizer0] No change in size detected
iframeResizer.contentWindow.js:140 [iFrameSizer][iFrameSizer0] Trigger event: mutationObserver: [object HTMLInputElement] attributes
iframeResizer.contentWindow.js:140 [iFrameSizer][iFrameSizer0] Trigger event: parentIFrame.size()
iframeResizer.contentWindow.js:140 [iFrameSizer][iFrameSizer0] Trigger event lock on
iframeResizer.contentWindow.js:140 [iFrameSizer][iFrameSizer0] Sending message to host page (iFrameSizer0:2902:720:size)
iframeResizer.contentWindow.js:140 [iFrameSizer][iFrameSizer0] Sending message to host page (iFrameSizer0:0:0:scrollTo)
resizer.js:1 [iFrameSizer] iFrameSizer0 height set to 2902px
resizer.js:1 [iFrameSizer] iFrameSizer0 height set to 0px
iframeResizer.contentWindow.js:140 [iFrameSizer][iFrameSizer0] Trigger event: mutationObserver: [object HTMLDivElement] attributes
iframeResizer.contentWindow.js:140 [iFrameSizer][iFrameSizer0] No change in size detected
iframeResizer.contentWindow.js:140 [iFrameSizer][iFrameSizer0] Trigger event cancelled: resize
iframeResizer.contentWindow.js:140 [iFrameSizer][iFrameSizer0] Trigger event lock off
iframeResizer.contentWindow.js:140 [iFrameSizer][iFrameSizer0] --
```

upon resizing

```
[iFrameSizer][iFrameSizer0] Trigger event: mutationObserver: [object HTMLDivElement] attributes
iframeResizer.contentWindow.js:140 [iFrameSizer][iFrameSizer0] Trigger event lock on
iframeResizer.contentWindow.js:140 [iFrameSizer][iFrameSizer0] Sending message to host page (iFrameSizer0:2903:721:mutationObserver)
iframeResizer.contentWindow.js:140 [iFrameSizer][iFrameSizer0] Trigger event cancelled: resize
resizer.js:1 [iFrameSizer] iFrameSizer0 height set to 2903px
iframeResizer.contentWindow.js:140 [iFrameSizer][iFrameSizer0] Trigger event: mutationObserver: [object HTMLDivElement] attributes
iframeResizer.contentWindow.js:140 [iFrameSizer][iFrameSizer0] No change in size detected
iframeResizer.contentWindow.js:140 [iFrameSizer][iFrameSizer0] Trigger event cancelled: resize
iframeResizer.contentWindow.js:140 [iFrameSizer][iFrameSizer0] Trigger event: mutationObserver: [object HTMLDivElement] attributes
iframeResizer.contentWindow.js:140 [iFrameSizer][iFrameSizer0] Sending message to host page (iFrameSizer0:2906:723:mutationObserver)
iframeResizer.contentWindow.js:140 [iFrameSizer][iFrameSizer0] Trigger event cancelled: resize
resizer.js:1 [iFrameSizer] iFrameSizer0 height set to 2906px
iframeResizer.contentWindow.js:140 [iFrameSizer][iFrameSizer0] Trigger event: mutationObserver: [object HTMLDivElement] attributes
iframeResizer.contentWindow.js:140 [iFrameSizer][iFrameSizer0] Trigger event cancelled: resize
iframeResizer.contentWindow.js:140 [iFrameSizer][iFrameSizer0] No change in size detected
iframeResizer.contentWindow.js:140 [iFrameSizer][iFrameSizer0] Trigger event lock off
iframeResizer.contentWindow.js:140 [iFrameSizer][iFrameSizer0] --
```

Any advice would me much appreciated, I think i have read davidjbradshaws implementation guide correctly but I cannot fathom out why this one part should'nt work

Thank you in advance.

Added new log as requested by @david-bradshaw

```
iframeResizer.contentWindow.js:140 [iFrameSizer][res-iframe] Sending message to host page (res-iframe:3703:850:mutationObserver)
resizer.js:1 [iFrameSizer] res-iframe height set to 3703px
iframeResizer.contentWindow.js:140 [iFrameSizer][res-iframe] Trigger event cancelled: resize
iframeResizer.contentWindow.js:140 [iFrameSizer][res-iframe] Trigger event lock off
iframeResizer.contentWindow.js:140 [iFrameSizer][res-iframe] --
iframeResizer.contentWindow.js:140 [iFrameSizer][res-iframe] Trigger event: Touch Start
iframeResizer.contentWindow.js:140 [iFrameSizer][res-iframe] No change in size detected
iframeResizer.contentWindow.js:140 [iFrameSizer][res-iframe] Trigger event: Touch End
iframeResizer.contentWindow.js:140 [iFrameSizer][res-iframe] No change in size detected
iframeResizer.contentWindow.js:140 [iFrameSizer][res-iframe] Trigger event: Mouse Down
iframeResizer.contentWindow.js:140 [iFrameSizer][res-iframe] Trigger event: Mouse Up
iframeResizer.contentWindow.js:140 [iFrameSizer][res-iframe] Trigger event: mutationObserver: [object HTMLInputElement] attributes
iframeResizer.contentWindow.js:140 [iFrameSizer][res-iframe] Trigger event lock on
iframeResizer.contentWindow.js:140 [iFrameSizer][res-iframe] Sending message to host page (res-iframe:2345:850:mutationObserver)
iframeResizer.contentWindow.js:140 [iFrameSizer][res-iframe] Sending message to host page (res-iframe:0:0:scrollTo)
resizer.js:1 [iFrameSizer] res-iframe height set to 2345px
resizer.js:1 [iFrameSizer] res-iframe height set to 0px
iframeResizer.contentWindow.js:140 [iFrameSizer][res-iframe] Trigger event cancelled: resize
iframeResizer.contentWindow.js:140 [iFrameSizer][res-iframe] Trigger event lock off
iframeResizer.contentWindow.js:140 [iFrameSizer][res-iframe] --
```

Answer (score 0):

Their is nothing in that log to show iFrameResizer changing the height to zero. So you must have something else acting on it.

Comment: Hi @david-bradshaw there is the line:-

resizer.js:1 [iFrameSizer] iFrameSizer0 height set to 2902px
resizer.js:1 [iFrameSizer] iFrameSizer0 height set to 0px

Comment: Need to see all of the log.

Comment: I cant paste the full log in here from page load to final resize but here is the last portion

Comment: hi @david-bradshaw, did you manage to take a look at the requested log?

Comment: I need the whole thing or a link to a site with logging turned on.